# Android Billing Client library : How to specify Developer Payload(extra data)

Tags: android, play-billing-library

I am trying to use the new [Android Billing Client library(1.0)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html)

Previously, while trying to perform a purchase, there was option to add extra data to the intent.

However, when using the new library, things have been simplified to a great degree. But is there way to add the developer payload(extra string) to the purchase flow ?

Comment: See my answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470237/6478047

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **new version of the billing library supports the developer payload**.

You can set the developer payload when acknowledging the purchase or consuming it.

```
val client: BillingClient = ...
val listener: AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = ...

val acknowledgePurchaseParams =
AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
    .setPurchaseToken(/* token */)
    .setDeveloperPayload(/* payload */)
    .build()

client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, listener)
```

[Attach a developer payload in Android Billing Library v2.0](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#attach_a_developer_payload)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to it, the names have been changed, hence the confusion.

The BillingFlowParams builder, exposes a function named `setAccountId(String accountId)`. The definition for this function is :

> Specify an optional obfuscated string that is uniquely associated with the user's account in
>         your app.
>        If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular activity, such as many
>         devices making purchases on the same account in a short period of time. Do not use the
>         developer ID or the user's Google ID for this field. In addition, this field should not
>         contain the user's ID in cleartext. We recommend that you use a one-way hash to generate a
>         string from the user's ID and store the hashed string in this field.

I think  this is the new way to specify developer payload, or any extra string for extra layer of validation.
So the code will look something like this :

```
private fun makePurchaseFromGoogle(developerPayload : String) {
    val purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSku(product.sku)
            .setType(product.type)
            .setAccountId(developerPayload) // dev-payload
            .build()
    googleBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, purchaseParams)
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve it?

Comment: account id is not payload

Comment: See my answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470237/6478047